# How can I change the periods in x axes in matplotlib?

Tags: matplotlib

I would like to change the period of number in x-axes. It was divided automatically. How can I change it?

[image: Graph-1]

Comment: Hi, It would be easy if you could include the code that you have used to plot the graph

Comment: Try ax.set_xticks()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the x-ticks of the plot using [matplotlib.pyplot.xticks](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xticks.html#matplotlib-pyplot-xticks) similarly for y

Usage example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
w = 4
h = 3
d = 70
plt.figure(figsize=(w, h), dpi=d)
x = [1, 2, 4, 3, 0]
plt.yticks((0, 2, 4))
plt.xticks((0.5, 2, 4))
plt.plot(x)
```

Would result in

[image]